# Running Java Class file from Excel VBA

Tags: java, excel, vba

I have created a Java main class file which takes 3 arguments (RGB) and have ran this from the command prompt using `java getCol 255 255 0` This works fine but I am now trying to run this from Excel VBA. So far I have tried:

`Shell "C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\getCol.class 200 200 0", vbMaximizedFocus`

This returns an "Invalid procedure call or argument" run time error. Could I please get some advise on how to do this and also, if there is a better suited way of doing this.

Comment: I have tried: Shell 
"java C:\Users\suraj\Desktop\getCol.class 100 100 0", vbMaximizedFocus
and it runs in VBA without errors, but nothing else happens. I mean that the Java code does not seem to run.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a simple batch script to execute the java class. This was then called from VBA.